# compute exit code based on text output

Tags: bash, grep, exit-code

I have a program which returns always zero exit code, even in case of an internal error. In case of an error there is additional output to standard output like:

```
# always-zero-exit
Error: Line: 1, Column: 1
some further scary error description....
```

Can someone please advice how to make a short bash workaround like the one below:

```
# always-zero-exit > search-for-string-'Error'-and-returns-non-zero-if-found
```

Comment: `! grep Error`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As *Biffen* suggested in the comment, use `! grep ERROR_PATTERN`.

Example:

```
# Tiny test command that exit with status 0 and 
# prints errors into STDOUT:

echo 'Error: Line: 1, Column: 1' > out.log
! grep -q 'Error' out.log
echo $?
# Prints: 1

# Same, no errors:

echo 'Line: 1, Column: 1' > out.log
! grep -q 'Error' out.log
echo $?
# Prints: 0
```

---

You may want to use more complex error message processing, for example:

```
! grep -Pqi '(error|fail|exception)' out.log
```

---

Here, `grep` uses the following options:
`-P` : Use Perl regexes.
`-i` : Use case-insensitive matching.
`-q` : Quiet; do not write anything to standard output. Exit immediately with zero status if any match is found.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`grep` manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)